# Make the automatic duplicate answer flag on the second (third, fourth, etc.) post

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, automatic-flags

Currently, when a user posts the same answer to multiple questions, the original answer gets flagged. However, this makes the quick delete button delete the original answer. In almost all cases (all I can think of) the answer that should be deleted is the duplicate. Please have community flag that one instead.